# Stereo line-level converter: Odd grounding?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ground

I'm coming from a stock Dodge headunit, which has regular analog output that goes up to 10 volts. Nothing fancy, when I had it going straight to the amp it worked fine. It's going into a regular JL amplifier, with a max input of 4v. I was sold a Raptor LOC15 converter to bring the voltage down.

Here's a diagram of what I'm working with. On the left, we have the inputs. They're coming from the source unit. To the right are the outputs, that are heading to the amplifier. This board is supposed to bring the 10v from the source unit down to something more acceptable:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNCIo.png]

Ground... I can't figure out where I should ground it to. Chassis ground? Input ground? No ground?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are intending?  The diagram is a little misleading.  The diagram is for balanced inputs, unbalanced outputs-- but the output L-/R- connections is not correctly labeled.   So... What do you want?  Knowing what connectors you want would be a good start.

Comment: Sorry, messed up there! On the left, we have the inputs. They're coming from the source unit. To the right are the outputs, that are heading to the amplifier. This board is supposed to bring the 10v from the source unit down to something more acceptable. I just can not figure out where the ground input gets hooked up to.

Comment: But is the source unit spitting out a balanced signal?  And what's the connector?  And is the amp taking a balanced inputs?  Connector?  These are important things to know if you want to get the best audio quality with the least amount of fuss.  The diagram, as drawn, might work but I wouldn't suggest it as it's not really a balanced circuit.

Comment: I just had to look up balanced audio to understand what you're saying. The head unit only had positive and negative for right and left, it is not balanced - nothing in the system is balanced. There is no connector, just bare wires. Did the guy at the store just sell me the wrong thing?

Comment: I'm concerned that the diagram that you have might have safety issues.  Without knowing a lot more about the head unit _AND_ the amplifier you want to connect it to I cannot say what the proper connection method could be.  So, without more info I'd tentatively say that the guy at the store did sell you the wrong thing.  I should point out that I'm a Sr. Electrical Engineer at a large professional audio company, so I know a thing or two about blowing up audio equipment.

Comment: Wow! Amazing to see such well-qualified people on here. (I spend a lot of time on stackoverflow; it's much more rare to find professionals on there.) Anyways, I didn't want to mention specifics initially because I'm not sure of policies.. but I'm coming from a stock Dodge headunit, which has regular analog output that goes up to 10 volts. Nothing fancy, when I had it going straight to the amp it worked fine. It's going into a regular JL amplifier, with a max input of 4v. I was sold a Raptor LOC15 converter to bring the voltage down. Should I just head off to radioshack, build  my own?

Comment: Are you trying to connect a speaker output to a line input?

Comment: It's not really a speaker output, it originally went to a factory amplifier... but yeah, basically, that would be the same setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so here's the deal.  First you need to determine if the output of the head unit is balanced or unbalanced.  This is fairly easy to figure out.  First, find a GND connection.  This could be a signal on another connector, or use the chassis ground.  With the unit off, measure the resistance from GND to the negative output (left or right channel, doesn't matter).  If the resistance is nothing (less than 1 ohm) then you have an unbalanced output, more than 1 ohm and you have a balanced output.  Next, look at the diagrams I've included here (you might have to enlarge them to make all the lines show up, right click on the image and select "View Image" or something similar):
[image: Audio Adapters]

From those diagrams, pick the one that matches what you need.  You'll probably need the balanced to unbalanced, or unbalanced to unbalanced.  I've included the other two for completeness sake, and for the sake of explanation.

The first, balanced to balanced, has three sections.  The first is a balanced voltage divider made from R1-R3.  It is important to note that R1 and R2 must have the same value.  C1 and C2 are the DC blocking caps.  The higher the cap value used, the lower the frequency response.  1 uF will work for some things, but 10 uF is better.  Values up to 68 uF is not unreasonable.  Then finally R4 is used to make the output tend to settle to zero volts when the thing is turned off.

In the unbalanced out versions you'll notice that R2 and R3 are connected in series.  These could (and should) be replaced with a single resistor, but I left them separate to show that their functionality has not gone away when compared to balanced in-balanced out. 
These unbalanced out versions are also similar to your diagram.  To make the similarities more obvious, R1=4.7K and R2+R3=680 ohms.

The ultimate way to do this is with an transformer.  I show this only for amusement, as a good quality audio transformer will run about US$100.  Not worth it for most applications.

I should also point out that I drew the caps as a polarized cap.  For this application it's better that the + terminal be on the input side, but this isn't true for other applications.  I recommend using a simple aluminum electrolytic cap.  There is the chance the cap will be reverse biased (a.k.a. reverse polarity), but that's OK in this application.  There are better caps to use, but they are going to be expensive and have little audible benefit over the aluminum electrolytic.

I hope this is useful!

Comment: @David Kessner: This is a very good answer... I'll keep this info for future reference, thanks!

Comment: Wish I could upvote this 100 times! Before today I didn't even know these differences existed. The resistance between the lighter gnd and the negatives were 6.5k-ish, so I'm going to say this is balanced. (Glad the stereo store guy was right!) I actually just put together this circuit: http://tkk.fi/Misc/Electronics/circuits/speaker_to_line.html and tried it. Thankfully it sorta worked, and I didn't break anything. Anyways from what I can see, the bottom left is what I have and need; all I would have to do is add a 100k resistor in to settle it to zero (That necessary if I have a remote wire?)

Comment: The 100K resistor isn't strictly required.  If it's easy, do it.  Otherwise don't worry about it.  And there isn't anything magical about 100K.  Anything from 50k to 400k will work.

Comment: Cool, cool. So I basically will just have to ground the "adapter" out to the chassis. Thanks!

By the way, that bottom right one, the transformer - what's the difference between that and a ground loop isolator?

Comment: The turns ratio of the transformer is not 1:1.  It's whatever is needed to get the right voltage at the output.

Comment: So I just finished wiring all of this up, and it seems like it's working (the voltage measurements are.. kinda weird) but, when I turn the volume all the way down, there's a very low frequency humming noise that wasn't there before. I tried putting in a 100k resistor, and the humm was there anyways. Any idea on what could be causing this? Might it be harmful?

Comment: Well, I actually just turned the truck back on and I'm hearing alternator wine. Looks like this is a ground loop... does that sound logical? If so, I already have a 2-channel ground loop isolator that I installed when I hacked into my stereo to allow my ipod to play through it - couldn't charge the iPod at the same time. Could I relocate that to between the headunit and amplifier? Or should I leave it - is it possible to have 2 ground loops?

Comment: And my truck just hit 18 volts going down the highway! I turned the radio off, put the truck in neutral and turned it off. Turned it back on and its staying at 14. Possibly still a ground loop? Is that a symptom?

Comment: @kavisiegel Sorry, I somehow missed your replies.  Car power systems are notoriously noisy environments, and that's getting into your sound somehow.  It's probably not a ground loop.  There are two ways it could be getting in:  Noise on the power, and EMI getting into the audio signals themselves-- or both.  Try powering the system off of a separate battery to confirm or eliminate the truck power system as the source.  After that, it's all filtering and shielding.

Answer (score 2):

One purpose for such a circuit is to take a speaker level output (balanced) from the head unit and attenuate it so it can be used as the line level input to your amplifier or active crossover system.  So the resistive divider matters in order to get the proper line level input based on the maximum power capability of the head unit.  You will also want to make sure the resistors are rated properly for the power from the head unit.  For example let's say the resistors total ~5.3k ohms and your head unit can deliver, say 30 watts RMS into an 8 ohm load.  Typically the maximum voltage of the output of the head unit is what matters as you spec the resistors.  V^2/R = Power, so in this example 30 watts = V^2/8, solve for V and you get Sqrt(240)= 15 volts RMS.  So how much power is going through your divider?  15^2/5.3k = 45 mW.  So 1/8 Watt resistors would work great.  If you pick smaller resistors in the divider, say 470 and 68, you get the same ratio but you need 1/2 watt resistors instead.  Line level inputs are high impedence and prefer the sources to be low impedence to minimize noise.  So lower value divider resistors are better.  I use the 470 ohm and 68 ohm, 1/2 watt resistors to make this. The smaller cap will also result in better low end response.  Z(cap)=1/(2*PI*freq*C)  When the freq is such that Z(cap) = Rtot, that's where your low end starts to cut off.  So 1uF, 530 ohms, means low cut at 300Hz.  Go with 10uF and you get a 30Hz low cut.  If you have 5.3k ohms, you have to go with 100uF to get that low end.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Scott. I don't know if you noticed that the accepted answer dates from March 2011 so I doubt that he's still got the radio and wiring on the floor of his vehicle. Your answer may still help someone. You could improve it easily by inserting a few paragraph breaks (enter, enter) at the right places to break up the wall of text.

Comment: Thanks for the coaching.  Didn't notice the date.  First time in, I wasn't sure what my editing options were.  Thought maybe if I hit the enter button, it would post my answer prematurely.  I will pay more attention to structure now as well as content.

Comment: The post editor is quite robust. The comment editor _does_ post the comment on pressing enter. This has caught me out several times. Copy the partially completed text, delete the comment and paste it into a new one if you don't want anyone to see it until you're finished. There's also an excellent schematic editor built in. It's worth spending 20 minutes playing with all the components on this - double-click for properties and options. You can do quite tasty, readable schematics (as well as awful ones).

Comment: I've been searching for hours and this looks like the most informative answer so far. The only thing that looks backwards to me is the capacitor sizing. It seems to be backwards. Because it is a part of the denominator, the smaller the value the higher the Z(cap). Since Z(cap) has to equal Rtot, the higher Rtot, the smaller the capacitor necessary. Disclaimer: I am going based on the answer as presented.

Answer (score 1):

Put a capacitor between the input return ground and your system ground, and also put a high value resistor (1 Mohm probably) as well.   That way, each ground can stay at their respective ground potential, but the high-ohm resistor will "pull down" either grounds that might be floating.   The capacitor will allow signal current to flow on the ground line as needed.  Make sure you have a high enough voltage capacitor to accomodate the signal voltage AND the likely ground voltage differential.