# How to convert 4 wire speaker level output to 3 wire line level

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have a Shark Motorcycle Audio radio that has differential (balanced) output for the left and right channels. I wish to convert this to a 3 wire line level signal to the input of my headphone amplifier. A similar question was posed in March of 2011 under the topic: [Stereo line-level converter: Odd grounding?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/stereo-line-level-converter-odd-grounding)

An answer by user3524 includes a diagram which I have a question about. What are the correct resistor values for R1, R2, and R3. In the balanced in, balanced out section, it is stated that R1 and R2 must be equal. The value of R3 is not addressed. In the balanced in, unbalanced out (which is what I need) R2 and R3 are combined and a value of 680 ohms is suggested, with a value of 4.7K suggested for R1. I don't understand how the R2/R3 combo could be less than R!, if R1 and R2 are supposed to be equal. Can anyone help explain? Thanks.

Comment: The answer to the previous question was provided by user3624. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R1 and R2 no longer should be equal in the balanced-in/unbalanced-out circuit. As a matter of fact, R2 should completely *disappear*, its purpose in the balanced-in/balanced-out circuit (along with C2 that also disappeared) was to keep the balanced signals differential aspect (i.e. not ground referenced) in both input and output.

The author of that answer placed R2 there so that one could notice circuit simmetries, but perhaps he did not put much thought into possible ambiguities. I'm not an audio engineer like the author of that answer, but from my understanding, it is safe to ignore R2 existance and place a single R3 of 680 ohms. The author even states: *these [R2 and R3] could (and should) be replaced with a single resistor*.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the 4 wires are + and - for left and right channels? If yes, then just connect the two - together and make that "ground". Now you have 3 wires.

If you want to attenuate you can use a voltage divider on each + to ground.

However, if you used two of those mini Radio Shack output transformers that are 1K:8R that will step down the signal ~11 to 1 and it will very easily drive headphones directly. And it's totally passive. Then adjust the level on the radio as usual (although you cannot use voltage dividers if you're going to drive headphones directly).

Comment: The speakers are often driven with a bipolar drive so you CANNOT just join the -ve  wires together in a car radio as one may be driving in opposition to the other.  If you make use of the line transformers to isolate and level adjust then you can also select one of each transformer output as a common.

Comment: I agree with KalleMP, the L&R- outputs cannot be commoned. I came close to melting the amplifier by trying that.